# C Programming sockets in windows - winsock2.h linking libraries?

Tags: c, sockets, visual-studio-code, mingw

I am trying to build some Windows socket code using C.  I've started with the following basic code to initialize WinSock:

```c
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");
};
```

When I run the code, I get errors such as:

`undefined reference to '__imp_WSAStartup'`

A quick google suggests this is to do with needing a library linking - `ws2_32`?

I was using Cygwin, but apparently this is trying to mimic a POSIX environment in Windows and hence MinGW is much more suited in this instance.  Hence I've installed this and updated settings in VSCode to use it.

Now my problem is, I'm not sure how to link the required library.  Do I do it within my program by adding some code?  Do I do it in some sort of separate terminal?

This is all new to me.

Comment: If your compiler supports it, you can use `#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")` (or equivalent) directly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cygwin as an environment to code is not recommenced. (*[See pros and cons of using Cygwin](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-Cygwin-and-how-does-it-compare-to-running-Linux-in-a-virtual-machine)*.) Pick one environment or the other.  i.e. run `GCC` in either Windows or Linux, but not both.  *[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)* comes bundled with `GCC`, and has versions that can be used in either Windows or Linux.

And yes, the error message `undefined reference to` indicates that although the header file is there, the library it refers to is not.  It needs to be linked using `Ws2_32.lib`.

If using the Code::Blocks IDE for example, the instruction for linking a library *[are here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=How+to+link+a+libraray+in+Code%3A%3ABlocks)*.

Or, from the command line using `GCC`:

> For example, if I have a library named libmine.so in
>   /home/newhall/lib/ then I'd do the following to link it into my
>   program:

```
   $ gcc -o myprog myprog.c  -L/home/newhall/lib -lmine  //Linux

   C:\> gcc -o myprog myprog.c  -LC:\home\newhall\lib -lmine  //Windows
```

*[...more on gcc command line here](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html)*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm using VSCode.  Its the `command line using GCC:` which I'm struggling with - where would I access that? Thanks

Comment: Does the example line shown above help you figure it out?

Comment: right - so if I'm following correctly the gcc commands can be simply entered into a normal windows command prompt.  If that's the case I'll have a play later tonight

Comment: Yes, that is what the `gcc` examples above are indicating.  (except that example is using a Linux path :). Windows of coarse will be something like `C:\dir1\dir2\libname.lib`. Just verify the library exists on your system and enter actual path as shown.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The line that links your code to a `.exe` file needs to include `-lws2_32` after the `.o` or `.c` file.
So in your case if your program is called `myprogram.c` you would need to run:

```
gcc -o myprogram.exe myprogram.c -lws2_32
```

or if you compile and link in seperate steps:

```
gcc -c -o myprogram.o myprogram.c
gcc -o myprogram.exe myprogram.o -lws2_32
```